# How does JOIN work exactly in SQL

Tags: sql, database, join

I know that joins work by combining two or more tables by their attributes, so if you have two tables that both have three columns and both have column `INDEX`, if you use `table1 JOIN table2` you will get a new table with 5 columns, but what if you do not have a column that is shared by both `table1` and `table2`? Can you still use `JOIN` or do you have to use `TIMES`?

Comment: you can join any fields you want, though that join won't make any sense. all the join does is apply whatever test you specified. if the result comes out true, then the two records are "joined". so you could have `select * from doctors join fruits on doctor.specialty=fruits.seed_count`, and get results - nonsensical results, but still results.

Comment: You would not get a "new table" with 5 columns; unless using the `USING` syntax, you would get two "INDEX" columns.

Comment: In order to be joined in a meaningful way the tables should be related.  Are you familiar with Primary Key / Secondary Key concepts?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: If you do a join without specifying any shared columns, you get a `CROSS JOIN`, which is a full cross product between both tables. If the two tables have 10 and 20 rows, you'll get a result with 200 rows, every pair of rows in the original tables.

Answer (score 2):

Join is not a method for combining tables.  It is a method to select records (and selected fields) from 2 or more tables where every table in the query must carry a field that can be matched to a field in another table in the query. The matched fields need not have the same name, but must carry the same type of data.  Lacking this would be like trying to create meaning from joining a list of license plates of cars in NYC, with height data from lumberjacks in Washington state -- not meaningful. 
Ex:)

```
Select h.name, h.home_address, h.home_phone, w.work_address,      
w.department 
from home h, work w
where h.employee_id = w.emp_id
```

As long as both columns: employee_id and emp_id carry the same information this query will work

Comment: "As long as both columns: employee_id and emp_id carry the same information this query will work".  That's a little vague IMHO.  It won't "work" if even one employee is missing from the `home` table?

Comment: Morpheus:  The op asked about joins -- I didn't push down into outer or (left) joins.  The join will work -- it will return matched pairs -- it answers the question: What is the home information of all employees. -- Admittedly, if a home record doesn't exist in department it won't be reported on. If we were seeking the work department of all say school parents, we'd want to left join to department to account for those where we were missing department information.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Access, to get five rows from a three column table joined to a two column table, you'd use:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1;
```

You can query whatever you want, and join whatever you want, though.

If your one table is a list of people, and your other is a list of cars, and you want to see what people have names that are also models of cars, you can do:

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Age, Table2.Make, Table2.Year
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name = Table2.Model;
```

Only when Name is the same as Model will it show a record.

This is the same idea for joining tables in any relational DBMS I've used.

Answer (score 0):

You are right you can join two tables even if they do not have shared column.

Join uses primary to prevent mistakes on inserting or deleting when user trying to insert record that does not has a parent one or some thing like this.

join methods has many types you can view them here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

LEFT JOIN: select all records from first table, then selecting all records from second table that fulfilling the condition after `ON` clause.

Answer (score -3):

you can't join the tables if they do not share a common column. If you can find a 3rd table that has common columns with table1 and table2 you can get them to join that way. so join table2 and tabl3 on a common column and than join table3 back to table1 on a common column.

Comment: How about a `FULL JOIN`?

Comment: not sure who down voted this but with out a relationship between the 2 tables you cannot do any useful joins.

Comment: Suppose you have two small tables (each with one row).  You can use a `CROSS JOIN`.  They don't even have to be small tables, but I would advise against it if not.

Comment: ok and how do those 2 record sets relate, they don't the data becomes useless. lets try and help rather than confuse people.

Comment: Your ignorance is formidable. Even related tables does not have to share a column. Relations can be established based on multiple columns, parts of a column, etc.

Comment: Downvotes are used to indicate your answer is NOT helpful.  It is a wrong answer.  false == "you can't join the tables if they do not share a common column"

Comment: are you guys serious right now. This is ridiculous. I'm just trying to keep it simple for the guy asking the question and if you want useful data you need a relationship between the 2 tables. How are you guys disagreeing with that.

Comment: @D4TAM4X "useful" is very dependent on needs; while I would agree JOINing relationless tables is rarely useful, there are occasions when it is. And while I didn't vote your answer down, its very first sentence is literally wrong.